# UICollectionView change flow direction on rotation

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

[image: Compact Height]

[image: Compact Width]

Hey, I'd like to obtain what you see in the pictures: in Compact Height mode (landscape iphone) both the red and the blue view have to take all screen vertically and half the screen horizontally. In Compact Width mode (portrait iphone)they have to take all the screen horizontally and half the screen vertically. Space between views should be same size in both modes.

I used to think I have to use size classes and auto-layout constraints, but everything I tried failed miserably.

Maybe I have to use a UICollectionView and change flow direction based on orientation (if that is even possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection view is probably overkill, because you don't want scrolling and that's the whole point of a collection view--by the time you do the sizing to stop it you'll have done all the work necessary to set a non-scrolling layout.

This is possible with Size Classes in IB. First, In general you will probably find it helpful to name the views in the Document Outline on the left in IB. You will also want to use this outline rather than try to grab the tiny constraint H-lines.

1. Set up all the constraints except 1) constraints linking the
   OrangeView and BlueView to each other, 2) the constraints linking
   the OrangeView to the top and left(leading), and 3) The constraints
   linking the BlueView to the bottom and right (trailing).
2. Change the size class setting at the bottom to w-Compact and
   h-Any in the funky box system. Now we're designing for a compact width, so  views on top of each other.
3. Create a constraints for vertical space for BlueView.bottom to
   OrangeView.Top. Also create constraint for OrangeView to
   superview.leading (or ledaing,margin) and BlueView to
   superview.trailing.margin. If you select any one of these constraints and look at the Size Inspector on the right (the ruler) you should see an "installed" checkbox not selected, and below that a w-Compact h-Any and another installed box, this one selected.
4. Now, while keeping the constraint selected just to see what happens, change the sizeClass selector at the bottom to w-Regular h-Any. Notice that in the Document Outline to the left, it should get grayed out.
5. Now we are designing for regular, so side-to-side. Add constraints linking the views for horizontal space, BlueView.trailing to OrangeView.leading. Also link OrangeView.top to the superview.top or top aligned to BlueView.top, and same for bottoms. You can manually edit the frame first; if not, IB will automatically fill in the wrong values, so edit these after you create them, and verify they are w-Regular and h-Any. With the ViewController selected, select "update frames" and the views should snap to their expected shape for the size class.

Let us know if this works for you or if it was unclear. Good luck!

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for writing such a detailed and exhaustive answer! IB can be quite non-intuitive sometime...

Comment: I'm still trying to learn auto-layouts and size classes: on step 1. when you say "setup all the constraints" do you mean: 1) blue-to-top 2) blue-to-leading 3) orange-to-bottom 4) orange-to-trailing ? Xcode complains I miss constraints for heights and widths for both blue and orange. I've tried setting equal widths and heights for blue and orange but it does not work "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." and so on...

Comment: Yes, the Xcode warnings are sometimes very valid and sometimes need to be ignored- it's why there's a "placeholder" option, just to quiet warnings if you know yours going to handle them in code.

Comment: Comment continued, sorry, on mobile: In this case, you will get warnings after step 1 because  you haven't given it all the information yet. However, maybe my answer was not as through as it needed to be because it does eventually need constraints linking the views to *all* sides and each other, or else it can't figure out how big they should be. Setting up to each margin should resolve height and width with one view in that axis. Any that changes, setup only when editing that size class. If it can't resolve for two views along the same axis, the equal heights and width should work for that.